# How execute existing shortcode in wp with javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, embed, shortcode

I am using [PDF Embedder](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/pdf-embedder/) to embed pdf into wp webpage.

I'd like it to embed pdf when a button is clicked.

When I add the pdf media PDF Embedder inserts shortcode in backend editor:

```html
[pdf-embedder url="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/securepdfs/2019/11/nameofpdf.pdf"]
```

I created a js button onlick function to execute this shortcode

```html
<script>
function EmbedPDF(){
[pdf-embedder url="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/securepdfs/2019/11/nameofpdf.pdf"];
}
</script>
```

However when clicking button I get error on console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

```html
<a href="/?pdfemb-serveurl=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsecurepdfs%2F2019%2F11%2Fnameofpdf.pdf" class="pdfemb-viewer" style="" data-width="max" data-height="max" data-mobile-width="500"  data-scrollbar="none" data-download="off" data-tracking="on" data-newwindow="on" data-pagetextbox="off" data-scrolltotop="off" data-startzoom="100" data-startfpzoom="100" data-download-nonce="f55003eba4" data-disablerightclick="on" data-toolbar="bottom" data-toolbar-fixed="off">titleofpdf<br/></a>;
```

Comment: shortcode are parsed in PHP then you need to do an ajax call in JavaScript : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 1):

As previous poster mentioned PHP Shortcodes are excecuted on the *server-side* thus cannot be excecuted via direct Javascript, for this you can make an AJAX call (depending on the type of output you're expecting)

You could try something as follows (untested but i think youäll get the idea) :)

**This code goes into your functions.php file:**

```
<?php
// Load your custom js file
function my_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery') );
    // Here we need to send the ajax_urladmin-ajax url as a variable to the external JS file since we can't use PHP to get the URI in Javascript
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );

// Add a method for opeing the PDF
function loadPDF() {
    $url = isset($_REQUEST["post_id"]) ? $_REQUEST["post_id"] : null;

    if(!$url) // { } Handle invalid URL / Perform checks

    echo do_shortcode('[pdf-embedder url="'.$url.'"]');
}

// Define our ajax hooks
// wp_ajax_nopriv_ = for visitors
// wp_ajax_ = for logged in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_loadPDF', 'loadPDF' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_loadPDF', 'loadPDF' );
?>
```

**This code goes into your custom js file:**

```
jQuery( document ).ready() {
    jQuery('.pdf-button').on('click', function() {
        // Get the URL that should be loaded
        var url = jQuery(this).data('url');

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url : ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            data : {action: "loadPDF", url: url},
            success: function(data){
                // Redirect the output to a container ie. div
                jQuery('.my-container').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Example HTML:**

```
<div class="btn pdf-button" data-url="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/securepdfs/2019/11/nameofpdf.pdf">
</div>

<div class="my-container">
<!-- PDF Output -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @kraddy I'm testing your code but I get errors on loading the main page in the domain. I wrapped the js code in function cos I'm using wp template that calls the function: function PDFEmbed(){yourcodehere} GET https://example.com/wp-content/themes/uncode/js/custom.js?ver=5.3 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Make sure that the js file (custom.js) is actually inside that folder since it reports 404 Not Found